# Can I use a USB memory stick to boot Ubuntu Server with RAID?

Tags: usb, raid

Loading Ubuntu Server 18.04. I have four 2TB drives, and I want to make two RAID 1 drives with them. My current understanding is that Ubuntu REQUIRES /boot to NOT be on a RAID, but everything else can be. Seems silly to tie up a 2TB drive for that. Can I use a 16GB USB drive for /boot, create the two mirrors, and put the rest of the OS on those?

If I can, it sounds smart to take that USB drive and make a mirror copy. If it does die, a quick swap gets the server back to business.

If possible, how do I proceed?

Comment: My experience is that cheap Micro SD cards only last about six months as a server.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron But if you use the MicroSD only for /boot then it has very limited I/O. It's accessed only when you boot or when you update the kernel. We've been using SD cards as boot drives in our VM infrastructure for years without failure.

Comment: I decided to give it a try. No problem laying out the partitions, including creating two RAID1 drives from 4 drives. Start the install. It appears to set up the USB drive with no issues, but immediately fails on creating the RAID. Log shows "failed to remove holders from %s, device" then repeats with "device" replaced with the two drives selected for the first RAID1. Drives appear bare when looking with fdisk.

Comment: The exact error is
OSError: [Errno Failed to remove holders from %s] /dev/sda
This occurs even when I am not identifying sda for use as either RAID or a partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a USB stick but it might be simpler to carve out a small (200MB) partition at the beginning of two of the disks and the software raid the remaining almost 2TB. Only one of the two carved out partitions actually has to be used as /boot but you might want to manually mirror them occasionally to have a backup boot partition.

Comment: How does this work with wear leveling? For a server does it concentrate wear on a SSD on one spot?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron This will not concentrate wear on one spot on the SSD. Wear leveling works even when the disk is partitioned.

Comment: I attempted this, but do not see how to do it. I am using the 18.04 installer. The RAID option will only let me select entire drives, not partitions.